# Extracting outer boundary of polygon (current polygon merged to one row but layer has holes creating small polygon needing removal) using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, extract, boundaries

I had to create boundary of raster layer, so I used raster to polygon to get the boundary. But the boundary has many holes based on the original raster which I want to get rid of as I only need the outer-boundary or extent for my analysis.

I have considered creating a new polygon and snapping the edge to this layer but I think there is a simpler way to do this?

Image below - referring to purple boundary

[image: Only want purple outer boundary - not these smaller holes]

[image: attributes]

Answer (score 2):

A simple way I remove holes from a polygon is to:

1. Go into edit mode and select the polygon
2. Click on modify button
3. Click on Edit vertices so vertices show up as green dots
4. In the modify panel your outer ring should be part 1, all holes are parts 2+.
5. Simply selecting a vertex will confirm this for you. Look for the flash on the screen.
6. Select all vertices in all others parts and click on delete (red cross)

[image: Screen shot]

If you have millions of polygons with millions of holes (which you don't actually say) then a Python solution would be a better solution.