# Extracting outer boundary of polygon with holes needing removal using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, donut-polygons

I used the dissolve boundaries tool dissolving by field value to group polygons by year of treatment. Now I have dissolved polygons with hundreds of holes that need to be removed (please see picture). I want to keep only the outer polygon boundaries.

A similar question was asked as [Extracting outer boundary of polygon (current polygon merged to one row but layer has holes creating small polygon needing removal) using ArcGIS Pro](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/369170), but solutions provided were useful for small edits.

Is there an automated solution for hundreds of edits?

[image: Example of large polygon with smaller polygons (holes) to be removed]

Comment: [Eliminate Polygon Part (Data Management) - ArcGIS Pro | Documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/eliminate-polygon-part.htm) is the tool.  Specify a percentage condition of 99% to remove everything but the outer boundary.

Answer (score 1):

Run multipart to single part on your dataset. Start editing output of above and use field calculator to run this:

```py
def outRing(shp):
 part=shp.getPart(0)
 pgon=arcpy.Polygon(part)
 return pgon
#-----
outRing( !Shape!)
```

on Shape field.